# boolean converter to print an image, just print the image name c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, boolean, ivalueconverter

I have a DataGridTextColumn containing a boolean, these booleans return TRUE or FALSE on the Column.

I want to replace this by two images, one for TRUE, one for FALSE.

this is the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DonneesBrutes" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResultatCollectionGrande}" Margin="10,65,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PrisEnCompte" Width="50" Binding="{Binding Path=Flag, Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter}}" Header="PEC"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

with the resource:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <local:BooleanConverter x:Key="BooleanConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

this is the converter:

```
public class BooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.Equals(true)) return @"booleanTrue.png";
        return @"booleanFalse.png";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The converter works, it changes what my DataGridTextColumn displays. Now it Displays "booleanTrue.png" for TRUE and "booleanFalse.png" but it doesn't display the images.

How can I display'em, what am I missing to print these images in my DataGrid?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a DataGridTextColumn you will require Template column to display Image within this Column and apply your binding in this template column only. let me show you the way

Your datagrid should be like this

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DonneesBrutes" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResultatCollectionGrande}" Margin="10,65,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
 <DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="PEC" x:Name="PrisEnCompte">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Height="50" Width="50" Source="{Binding Path=Flag, Converter={StaticResource booleanConverter}}"></Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

and your Boolean converter should be like this.

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value.Equals(true)) 
                return new Uri(@"C:\Users\pj827192\Desktop\Untitled.png");
            return new Uri(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Hydrangeas.jpg");
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Comment: The converter does not necessarily have to return Uris. It could be strings as well, as WPFs built-in type conversion to type ImageSource (the type of the Image control's `Source` property) works for both. Moreover, when the images are stored as assembly resources (which I would assume from OP), you would have to return valid [Resource File Pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly). Another alternative would be to directly create and return BitmapImage or BitmapFrame instances.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should return the markup for embedding the image instead of just the image name.

Comment: The images are on root of the solution, so adding an `\` before, is it what you mean?

Comment: No, I mean returning a string like:

<img src=”URL of image” alt=”alternate text” title=”infotip text” height=”preferred height” width=”preferred width” />

Comment: Is it possible to return a string like this on a DataGrid.Columns? I'll try. **EDIT** Seems to be impossible, it only takes DataGrid CheckBox/Combobox/Hyperlink/Template/Text Maybe one of'em could let me do what I want?

Comment: DataGridTemplateColumn seems to be the solution, I try.

Comment: Now it works. This is how I've done: `<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="PrisEnCompte" Width="50" Header="PEC">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Path=Flag, Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter}}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>`